# Error when compiling using 'make' command in fedora 17

Tags: makefile, compiler-errors, linux-kernel, fedora, system-calls

I'm trying to build a new kernel and add a new system call to that built kernel and when I try to recompile using 'make' command after creating the new system call I get this error.

```
scripts/Makefile.build:44: /usr/src/linux-3.0.42/block/helloworld/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/src/linux-3.0.42/block/helloworld/Makefile'.  Stop.
make: *** [block/helloworld] Error 2
```

If someone can help me with this I'll be thankful :)

Comment: what is the directory helloworld ? What's inside? I think the error message is clear

Comment: helloworld is where i created my new system call and makefile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kernel modules use a different version of make than you are probably used to. It greatly simplifies things, but can be a bit confusing at first. Here is documentation for kernel make: http://lwn.net/Articles/21835/

Here is tutorial on a hello world module:

The c code: http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x121.html

The corresponding makefile: http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x181.html

Answer (score 1):

Not to bring back an old post but I had a similar problem and I am surprised no one suggested this.

When editing the linux3-x-x/Makefile

you want to include your directory by modifying the line:

core-y      += kernel/ mm/ fs/ ipc/ security/ crypto/ block/

to

core-y      += kernel/ mm/ fs/ ipc/ security/ crypto/ block/ helloworld/

A simple mistake is to forget **THE SPACE** after each directory block/_helloworld/
The underscore represents a SPACE

IF YOU do not have that space then you will get the above error no matter what.

Just thought I would add this incase others are searching around for a response